# Split a Rectangle View Using the Diagonal in Swift UI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI and I'm trying to achieve something that is quite easy using UIKit. Basically, I want to draw something like this in a View:

[image]

I figured that I could use GeometryScanner but I didn't manage to make it work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own `Triangle`:

```
struct Triangle: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        return path
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Rectangle()
    .fill(Color.white)
    .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
    .overlay(
        Triangle()
            .fill(Color.red)
    )
```

Comment: Dammed, I completely forgot about maxY and maxX ! Thanks!